# MySQL trigger problem. How to repair it? ERROR 1442

Tags: mysql, triggers

I don't know how to make the trigger work. I already managed to make it pass with no errors, but now I have the problem from the title.

[Here is a photo of a schema of given database:](https://trello-attachments.s3.amazonaws.com/5c4cb315904536613d57a06d/5c4cb4215365ca8b7a7ff398/b959b43dd3de5df8b6472132d6a8cd34/image.png)

Thanks a lot for any help or ideas!

```
/* Trigger do liczenia Total w Platnosciach */

DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER t_Payments AFTER INSERT ON Payments
FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN

    /* Ciagniemy numer rezerwacji (ZALOZENIE: TYLKO JEDNO ZRODLO ROBIENIA REZERWACJI) */

    SET @bookID=0;
    SELECT b.BookID INTO @bookID
    FROM Bookings b
    ORDER BY b.BookID DESC
    LIMIT 1;

  /* Calosc Pokoju */

    SET @room=0;
    SELECT
      TRUNCATE((DATEDIFF(b.DepDate,b.ArrDate)*r.Price),2) INTO @room
    FROM Rooms r
      INNER JOIN Bookings b ON r.RoomID = b.RoomID
    WHERE 
      b.BookID = @bookID;

  /* Calosc Uslug */

    SET @serv=0;
    SELECT
      TRUNCATE(SUM(si.price),2) INTO @serv
    FROM Bookings b
      INNER JOIN Services se ON b.BookID = se.BookID 
      INNER JOIN ServInfo si ON se.code = si.code
    WHERE 
      b.BookID = @bookID;

  /* Kod wbicia w Payments Total*/

  UPDATE Payments
    SET Total=((@room)+(@serv))
  WHERE PaymentID=@bookID;
  END //

DELIMITER ;
```

ERROR 1442 (HY000): Can't update table 'payments' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

Trigger is supposed to make a calculation how much the reservation will cost.

Later I will try to make the very INPUT of the data in the first place impossible, because inputting 0 or soomething random is pointless if it will be replaced the very second it gets submitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error says it all: you can't update (rows in) the same table as which you created your trigger for. You can however modify your row that is about to be inserted by:

1. First, changing your trigger timing from `AFTER` to `BEFORE`
2. Secondly, alter the row that is about te be inserted

with:

```
CREATE TRIGGER t_Payments BEFORE INSERT ON Payments
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    -- Your magic here
    SET NEW.Total = ((@room)+(@serv));
END
```

Comment: Well... That explains a lot. Just one more thing: WHERE should stay, right?

Comment: No, there is no `WHERE` in this statement (missed the semicolon in my answer, just added it). You are altering the row that is triggering the event (hence the `NEW.`-prefix).

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you prefix it with `NEW.`, so `SET NEW.Total = ...;`. That error looks like you didn't. Otherwise try wether adding backticks works `SET NEW.``Total`` = ...;`  (replace with single backticks, can't add those in comment)

Comment: Nevermind. I just missed the semicolon, just like you. But I must have made a logical mistake, because now the VALUE of Total is "NULL"...